# How to Collapse Materil UI React Panel in mobile

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, material-ui, panel, collapsable

Hi i'm very new in react and material-ui. I create this profile example page

[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-swanson-njx8k)

I need when open in desktop browser see the both panel expanded, and when open on mobile the second section must be collapsed.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this in render()

```
let isMobile = false;

if (window.innerWidth <= 500) {
  isMobile = false;
} else {
  isMobile = true;
}
```

and this in the ExpansionPanel

```
           <ExpansionPanel
              defaultExpanded={isMobile}
            >
```